# How to lookup documentation for ASMX web services in MSDN?

Tags: web-services, asmx

What term do I use to lookup documentation for old school .asmx web services in MSDN?

I want to add authentication (username/password) so that each web method is authenticated before executing.

Since everything is WCF I can't find anything hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/webservices/doc/SoapHeaders.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.services.aspx